# Windows Graphics performace preferences seem to be ignored for OpenGL applications

Tags: c, windows, opengl, directx

In windows you can configure, for each application, if it should use the low-power GPU or the high performace GPU:

[image]

I have tried to set it to "Power saving" mode and it seems to work with DirectX aplications. However, it seems to be ignored for applications using OpenGL. My questions are: is it possible to do something so these settings apply to OpenGL programs too? Do I need to do something is my code to handle this correctly?

I know in DirectX there is `EnumAdapterByGpuPreference` which takes an [`DXGI_GPU_PREFERENCE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi1_6/ne-dxgi1_6-dxgi_gpu_preference). That enum has the same options as in the settings UI. But I don't think there is anything analogous in WGL.

---

Note: I already know the existence of these flags

```
__declspec(dllexport) DWORD NvOptimusEnablement = 0x00000001;
__declspec(dllexport) int AmdPowerXpressRequestHighPerformance = 1;
```

But I don't want to use them because my end goal is to, hopefully, find a way to run two instances of the same application, one in each GPU. I don't know if this will be possible but I have to try.

Comment: Try exploring tweaking with the Nvidia control panel options after you launch your application, and make sure it's using the settings you expect